# Why WebSockets doesn't apply SOP?

Tags: same-origin-policy, websocket

I can't understand why SOP ([same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)) cannot block Cross-Origin WebSocket Hijacking, I just read [this](https://dev.solita.fi/2018/11/07/securing-websocket-endpoints.html) article and I can't understand from where [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) requests comes from.

From where does WebSocket requests comes from, that SOP cann't block attacks related to it ?

Comment: See https://blog.securityevaluators.com/websockets-not-bound-by-cors-does-this-mean-2e7819374acc for an excellent write-up on why same-origin policy does not apply to WebSockets.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674199/why-is-there-no-same-origin-policy-for-websockets-why-can-i-connect-to-ws-loc is also helpful.

Comment: Websockets have a kind of *better* SOP. Instead of a policy, the server *actually checks* the origin.

Comment: @user253751: Except it doesn't. Got here trying to deal with a wss://127.0.0.1 messing up a non-HTTPS server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same-origin policy considers all of these origins to be different:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
ws://example.com
wss://example.com
```

So if browsers were to apply SOP rules to WebSockets, if a page at `https://example.com` tried to connect to a WebSocket at `wss://example.com` it would fail.

In theory WebSockets could have been designed to use CORS headers during the initial HTTP handshake, but these two technologies were developed at roughly the same time.

Comment: Are you sure that SOP will block a WebSocket webpage, because WebSocket doesn't even have a SOP Application, no ?

Comment: @nakE It won't in reality, I was talking about the hypothetical scenario if browsers were to use SOP for WebSockets.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a case where a user browses a page at evil.com, and scripting in the page served by evil.com attempts to make a cross-site websockets request to bank.com in an attempt to access the user's sensitive banking information.

The websockets connection begins with a handshake to bank.com using https protocol.  Because SOP does not apply to websockets, the scripting in the page served by evil.com will be able to access the response headers of the https handshake from bank.com, and send these response headers back to evil.com - but these are unlikely to contain any sensitive information.  After the https handshake, the connection upgrades to `ws` or `wss` protocol.  If bank.com does not support ws or wss protocol, then the connection will fail at that point.  So, websockets cannot be used (abused) in the same way that XHR or Ajax can be used (abused) to attempt to access sensitive cross-site information by making standard https requests across sites.

If bank.com does support websockets protocol, then the onus is on bank.com to prevent unauthorized cross-site requests.  In the websockets request to bank.com, the browser will send an `origin` header containing the origin of the page making the request (evil.com), and it is up to bank.com to validate the request based on the origin.